# UITableView Jerky, Loading Up To 10 Images Per Cell In ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Yes - this question has been asked a lot. The main solution I've found is utilizing drawRect for the tableViewCell, however I don't see how to implement it in this specific situation as my slow loading is specifically due to the complexity of my cell's subviews that are loaded from NIB

I'm loading X table view cells. Each cell has a label, a uiscroll view. The uiscroll view contains up to 10 items that are UIView's with subviews of their own for an image, title and subtitle. Which is obviously what's causing the jerky bottle neck.

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
HorizontalScroll *scroll = (HorizontalScroll *)[cell viewWithTag:TEN_ITEM_SLIDER_TAG_SLIDER];
        scroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 0);
        scroll.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5);
        scroll.pagingEnabled = NO;

        [scroll resetItems];
        NSArray *items = [cellData objectForKey:@"items"];
        NSMutableArray *scrollItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++) {
            NSDictionary *item = [items objectAtIndex:i];

            NSArray *scrollItemXIB = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ScrollItemView" owner:self options:nil];
            UIView *scrollItemView = [scrollItemXIB lastObject];

            NSString *userId = ([[cellData objectForKey:@"sliderType"] isEqualToString:@"stores"]) ? [item objectForKey:@"id"] : [item objectForKey:@"userId"];
            NSString *resourceName = ([[cellData objectForKey:@"sliderType"] isEqualToString:@"stores"]) ? [item objectForKey:@"avatar"] : [item objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];

            ArgumentButton *scrollItemButton = (ArgumentButton *)[scrollItemView viewWithTag:SCROLL_ITEM_TAG_ICON];
            scrollItemButton.argument = item;
            scrollItemButton.argumentTwo = [cellData objectForKey:@"sliderType"];
            [scrollItemButton setImageWithURL:[APIController resourceUrlForUserId:userId resourceName:resourceName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrollItemButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tenItemSliderItemSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[scrollItemView viewWithTag:SCROLL_ITEM_TAG_TITLE];
            NSString *title = ([[cellData objectForKey:@"sliderType"] isEqualToString:@"stores"]) ? [item objectForKey:@"storeName"] : [item objectForKey:@"title"];
            titleLabel.text = title;

            UILabel *subtitleLabel = (UILabel *)[scrollItemView viewWithTag:SCROLL_ITEM_TAG_SUBTITLE];
            NSString *subtitle = ([[cellData objectForKey:@"sliderType"] isEqualToString:@"stores"]) ? [item objectForKey:@"category"] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", [item objectForKey:@"price"]];
            subtitleLabel.text = subtitle;

            if ([[cellData objectForKey:@"sliderStyle"] isEqualToString:@"numbered"]) {
                UIImageView *badgeIcon = (UIImageView *)[scrollItemView viewWithTag:SCROLL_ITEM_TAG_BADGE_ICON];
                badgeIcon.hidden = NO;

                UILabel *badgeLabel = (UILabel *)[scrollItemView viewWithTag:SCROLL_ITEM_TAG_BADGE_LABEL];
                badgeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i + 1];
                badgeLabel.hidden = NO;
            }

            [scrollItems addObject:scrollItemView];
        }

        [scroll loadItems:scrollItems];
```

Comment: Do you have .h and .m file for your view scrollItemView?

Comment: Why you are using a scroll view? Did you tried using collection view?

Comment: Are the images you are using `Big` or, are you downloading images `synchronously` ?

Comment: Try comment this line `[scrollItemButton setImageWithURL:[APIController resourceUrlForUserId:userId resourceName:resourceName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];` and check.

Comment: scrollItemView does not have a .h and .m, would it be better to do drawing in the .h and .m of it if I made one?

Comment: Commenting out that line does not solve the jerkiness.

Comment: Images loaded with setImageWithURL are loaded using async with  SDWebImage.

Comment: It's definitely the fact that the HorizontalScroll is loading in up to 10 Subviews from a XIB. If I set the for loop to only load 1 subview per scroll, jerkiness goes away. If I do 2, comes back although not as bad. CPU is skyrocketing as I scroll as well. So it's definitely due to the drawing that it's jerking.. Not sure how to remedy this though? Any ideas?